# Expand FAQ answers when hovering their titles, with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a FAQ and want to make the answer for each question appear only when the question is hovered. I want to do this using HTML and CSS.

Bellow you can see what I wrote. I chose to wrap each question in a `faq` class so that I can select only the `p`s inside each question. When I hover `h3` nothing happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

            .faq p {
                display: none;
            }

            .faq h3:hover .faq p {
                display: block;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="faq">
            <h3>foo?</h3>

            <p>bar, bar</p>
            <p>bar, bar</p>
            <p>bar, bar</p>
        </div>

        <div class="faq">
            <h3>baz?</h3>

            <p>bar, bar</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know hovering the title might not be the best option, because if the user goes and hovers the answer the answer would disappear. I can handle that later. Right now I am only puzzled why this does not work as is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `.faq h3:hover .faq p` you are trying to select another `.faq` element inside the hovered `h3`, which does not exists.

Instead, try this css selector `~`:

```css
.faq p {
    display: none;
}

.faq h3:hover ~ p {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq">
            <h3>foo?</h3>

            <p>bar, bar</p>
            <p>bar, bar</p>
            <p>bar, bar</p>
        </div>

        <div class="faq">
            <h3>baz?</h3>

            <p>bar, bar</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Oh! I had thought (and tried) using `~` but I used `.faq ~ p`, which wouldn't work too. I understand now. Noob mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `~` selector:

> Selects every **`<p>`** element that are preceded by a **`h3:hover`** element ~edited from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```css
.faq h3:hover ~ p {
  display: block;
}
.faq p {
  display: none;
}
.faq h3:hover .faq p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq">
  <h3>foo?</h3>

  <p>bar, bar</p>
  <p>bar, bar</p>
  <p>bar, bar</p>
</div>

<div class="faq">
  <h3>baz?</h3>

  <p>bar, bar</p>
</div>
```